Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <keras.layers.merging.concatenate.Concatenate
I want to create complex multilayer wide and deep perceptron to handle California datasets. But the output layer refuses to take (input+ layer obtained from the deep path)
input= keras.layers.Input(shape=x_train.shape[1:])
hidden1=keras.layers.Dense(30,activation="relu")(input)
hidden2=keras.layers.Dense(30,activation="relu")(hidden1)
concat = keras.layers.Concatenate([input, hidden2])
output=keras.layers.Dense(1)(concat)

I have tried to run the code but I face an error message like this
Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <keras.layers.merging.concatenate.Concatenate object at 0x00000196962D5540>
Please give me an idea of how can I change my concatenate layer into a tensor so that the output layer accepts the concatenate layer

You need to use keras.layers.Concatenate()([input, hidden2]) -- note the extra parentheses. First create the layer, then call it. Just like any other layer.
Alternatively, you can use the functional variant keras.layers.concatenate([input, hidden2]) -- note the lowercase c.
